# ruby convert date string in past to another format

Tags: ruby, datetime

I'm trying to parse the following date string:

```
111005
```

to

```
20111005
```

I'm trying to use Date.parse, but it's treating it as 0011 instead of 2011:

```
Date.parse("111005").strftime("%y%m%d")
```

Any idea how I can do this with DateTime? Obviously I could just concat the 20 on the beginning, but I was hoping to avoid this.

Comment: How would the computer know if you want 2011, 1911, 2111, 1811, 2211, and so on? If your answer to my question is that it is obviously 2011, then why not concat 20?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid prepending '20' onto it? It is one line of code that is not expensive on the system. Is this a much smaller section of a much larger problem?

Comment: Date does treat it as 2011, you are representing it as 11. `Date.parse("111005").year` #=> 2011

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the year with century? That's the `%Y` option:

```
 Date.parse("111005").strftime("%Y%m%d")
 # => "20111005"
```